# How to fork() and exec() in this one?

Tags: c++, unix, system-calls

I'm writing my own shell, but no fork gives my child_pid = 0...
What's wrong there?

```
 while(true)
    {
        read_command(command);

        if ((child_pid = fork()) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't fork\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (child_pid == 0) //child
        {
            status=execl("./myShell" command);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(status); //parent
        }
    }
```

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: He means: how do you know `child_pid` is never 0? Did you try printing it?

Comment: Why do you get the return value of `execl` if you don't do anything with it ?

Comment: Also `wait(status)` should be `wait(&status)` assuming `status` is declared as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `(child_pid == -1)` is not entered... Is the father (`else`) branch entered twice (by both process) or what?

Anyway I can't see a bug in that snippet of code. If you're sure your execution flow gets there, and has an unpredictable behavior its because of a bug.

I doubt glibc is bugged on your system: my best guess is that your program has got a broken pointer that broke everything. This is the most common cause of this kind of really weird behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. Add a debug print in `if(child_pid == 0)` and make sure it is not called. If `fork` cannot create a child, it sets `errno` to indicate the error occurred.